# How can I search for photos taken at a specific time?

Tags: macos, photos, search

All my photos are in iPhoto and I want to be able to search for photos taken at a specific time. Happy to use an app or command to search at file system level from Terminal if I need to.

1. Smart Albums will let me do date, but not time.
2. Spotlight will let me search meta data, but I cannot figure out how I can do a fuzzy search on the `kMDItemContentCreationDate` field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out Aperture can do it with a Smart Album.

`Date` lets you specify `Capture Hour of Day`

`EXIF` lets you specify `Capture Hour of Day`, `Capture Minute of Hour` and even `Capture Second of Minute`

Interestingly, iPhoto honours and displays this Smart Album but will not let you edit it.

Hope that's of help.

Comment: You can also search based on that EXIF data with the Finder.

Comment: @MacLemon care to tell us how? I mentioned it in point 2 in the OP, but could not figure out how to only search the EXIF for time but not date

Comment: So you have to buy Aperture?

Comment: You should be able to find the old Aperture trial version.